# Custom Block to Product Page with selection attribute is not showing

Tags: product, attributes, magento2.3.3, catalog-prodct-view.xml

I am trying to create an option where I can select yes or no in the backend, and when it's set to yes, it adds a block with an image in the product page. Here's what I have so far:

1. I created a `Yes/No` Attribute called "`samsung_5_vjet_garanci`" and
   made sure its Visible on Catalog Pages on Storefront. Added it on a sample product, and set it to YES
2. Created a CMS Block with just the "`<div class="samsung"><img src="{{media url="wysiwyg/image.png"}}" alt="" /></div>`" with identifier "`samsung-garanci`"
3. Created a .phtml file and uploaded it `/app/design/frontend/vendor/themename/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/samsung.phtml`

```
<?php $_product = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product')
            ->load($_product->getId());

if ($_product->getAttributeText('samsung_5_vjet_garanci') == "Yes"): ?>

<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('samsung-garanci')->toHtml(); ?>

<?php endif; ?>
```

4. Added a block in catalog_product_view.xml

   ```
   <referenceContainer name="product.info.main">
       <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="samsung" as="samsung" after="-" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/samsung.phtml" />
   </referenceContainer>
   ```

But it's not working, what am I doing wrong, it's been 3 days figuring this out, and still nothing.
Thank you very much if you help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's `mentioned that you use Magento 1.9.x` ( as per the tags added), but I can see that you `have magento2 style of code` and `magento2 directory structure` in your layout XML (`catalog_product_view.xml`). ***In short there is a mixup of code. Check and Confirm your Magento version at first and then add the respective style of code***

In Magento 1,

`Create and register a custom theme`

The layout and template paths should be

`app/design/frontend/vendor/theme/layout/catalog.xml` better create a `local.xml` for layout overrides

`app/design/frontend/vendor/theme/catalog/product/view/samsung.phtml`

and in your layout XML it should be

```
<catalog_product_view>
    <reference name="product.info">
    <block type="catalog/product_view" name="samsung_brand" as="samsung.brand" template="catalog/product/view/samsung.phtml"/>
</reference>
</catalog_product_view>
```

So confirm your Magento version, learn the theme creation, directory structure and layout directives to be used according to the version of Magento.

In case of Magento2, it should be

`app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml`

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <!--
    /**
     * @copyright (c) 2020
     * @category StackExchange
     * @package StackExchange_Answers
     * @version 1.0.0
     */
    -->
    <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
        <body>
            <referenceContainer name="content">
                <referenceBlock name="product.info.main">
                    <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="samsung" as="samsung" after="-" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/samsung.phtml" />
                </referenceBlock>
            </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

`app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/samsung.phtml`

```
<?php /** @var $block \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\AbstractProduct */ ?>

<?php 

$_product = $block->getProduct();

// just to print your attribute value for your confirmation, you can comment or remove the print statement below if you want

echo '<br/>Sku : ' . $_product->getSku() .' | samsung_5_vjet_garanci: '. $_product->getData('samsung_5_vjet_garanci') .' | samsung_5_vjet_garanci: '.$_product->getSamsung5VjetGaranci();

if ($_product->getData('samsung_5_vjet_garanci')) {
    echo $block->getLayout()->createBlock(\Magento\Cms\Block\Block::class)->setBlockId('samsung-garanci')->toHtml();
}

?>
```

Comment: No it's Magento 2.3.3, my bad with the tags. can you please write the answer again with Magento 2 in mind?

Comment: @JadoBulku updated the answer with Magento2 code.

Comment: It worked, THANK YOU very much, been a week trying to figure it out but was looking at 1.9 answers I guess.

Comment: @JadoBulku You are welcome and  glad that you are able to sort this out eventually !

Answer (score 0):

First of all you don't need to get getAttributeText('.....) if you are using a yes/no attribute. It's better to use

```
<?php $_product = $this->getProduct(); // you don't need to load product its already present.

if ($_product->getAttribute('samsung_5_vjet_garanci')): ?>

<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('samsung-garanci')->toHtml(); ?>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: have I placed it correctly on catalog_product_view.xml?

Comment: Yes. It should be placed on catalog_product_view.xml

Comment: Thanks for helping me, but still doesnt show, maybe I should change the Container name? I have 2 with the same name:

Comment: Please check the screenshot http://prntscr.com/1039r1p

Comment: It thought you are working on magento1 but I understand that you're are using 2. So you are trying wrong code on wrong magento version.